# Persisting tokens with MSAL.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm building an ASP.NET application which connects to the Microsoft Graph API on behalf of a specific user. I'm attempting to use MSAL.NET to handle all the authentication, as is recommended by the documentation.

However, I've run into a significant issue around persisting the login. By default MSAL.NET stores the tokens in memory, so they are lost whenever the app restarts, which is a significant problem. I need the tokens to be stored persistently as access to the API will be needed without the delegated user being logged in at the same time, and I don't want to prompt them to re-authorise every time the app is restarted.

There are a number of alternative serialisation methods for the cache mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization?tabs=aspnet).

I attempted to use the SQL Server distributed cache method exactly as described in the documentation, however I didn't have any luck getting this to work. The cache table simply remained empty and the in-memory cache still appeared to be in use.

I'd appreciate any advice on getting the tokens to persist a restart. I'd like to avoid rolling my own (inferior) authentication and try to stick with MSAL.NET if at all possible.

EDIT - code snippet:

```
App = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(...)
    .WithClientSecret(...)
    .WithTenantId(...)
    .WithRedirectUri(...)
    .WithLegacyCacheCompatibility(false)
    .Build();

App.AddDistributedTokenCache(services =>
{
    services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
    {
        options.ConnectionString = @"...";
        options.SchemaName = "dbo";
        options.TableName = "TokenCache";
        options.DefaultSlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90);
     });
});
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Edited, it's identical to the documentation, and the TokenCache table has been created using the sql-cache tool.

Comment: The fact that it is still using the memory cache implies it is being wired up somewhere. Could `AddInMemoryTokenCache` be injected elsewhere in your code?

Comment: There are no references to `AddInMemoryTokenCache`, so that seems unlikely.

Comment: I have this problem too. Copied the setup exactly as the documentation and examples suggest; the cache isn't used. No error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing. I spotted somewhere (maybe a sample) that you need to call  `services.AddDistributedTokenCaches();` just above `services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>`.

I can't remember exactly but I'm assuming that something else is registered in that call that you need for the SQL one to work.